# i get correct output while compiling with 'python' but not with 'python3'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In the below python code

```
    var=input("Enter a number between 1 to 10:")
    if (var==1 or var==2 or var==3 or var==4 or var==5):
          print ('the entered number is between 1 to 5')
    elif (var==6 or var==7 or var==8 or var==9 or var==10):
          print ('The entered number is between 5 to 10')
    else:
          print ('Wrong value exiting!!')
```

When i run it in terminal~$ python name.py

Enter a number between 1 to 10:3

the entered number is between 1 to 5

when i run it in terminal~$ python3 name.py

Enter a number between 1 to 10:3

Wrong value exiting!!

What makes the difference ? & what i have to change in order to get the correct output when i compile with python3`?

---

***is there any simpler way of comparison instead of using*** *"or"* ***for every number ?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2:

```
var=input("Enter a number between 1 to 10:")
```

The above evaluates the expression, so it ends up with `var` potentially equalling a number. (And as a note should really be avoided)

In Python 3, `input` is the equiv. of `raw_input` in Python 2, so it returns a string - if you expect it to be a number you need to do `var = int( input("...") )` and be aware of any conversion errors that may occur:

There is the `in` operator:

```
if var in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
    pass
elif var in (6, 7, 8):
    pass
else:
    pass
```

Or, if you want a between operation, you can make use of the Python logic system:

```
if 1 <= var <= 5:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to your use of `input` - in Python 3.x, it is the same as `raw_input` in Python 2.x, meaning that it is turning it into a string as opposed to an integer. As for your comparison, you could try using `range`:

```
var=int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 10:"))

if var in range(1, 6):
      print ('the entered number is between 1 to 5')
elif var in range(6,11):
      print ('The entered number is between 5 to 10')
else:
      print ('Wrong value exiting!!')
```

Comment: To get the old behavior of `input()`, you can use `eval(input())`

Comment: @PaoloMoretti For gods sake, don't give OP ideas!

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer Haha, after all of the warnings against `eval` I've seen on this site, I'm afraid to even type it.

Comment: At the very least - `ast.literal_eval(input())`

Comment: @Markus You are rigth, I was just quoting the official [py3k release notes](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins). Using `eval()` is really a bad practice.